# composer require laravel/ui not working for php artisan make:auth in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, lumen

I am trying to run php artisan make:auth and get the error that make:provide command not found. I then tried to use the composer require larval/ui command but got an error saying

```
 illuminate/support v5.8.9 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.2, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.3, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.0.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.2.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.3.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.3.x-dev, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.0.1, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.1.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.2.0, 2.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[v1.3.0, 2.0.3].
    - Installation request for doctrine/inflector (locked at 2.0.3) -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[2.0.3].
reverting composer.json back to its orginal contents
```

I have seen posts about running the sudo-apt get install php command but I am using a Mac and have installed home-brew but not sure how to run the equivalent command. I assume there is a mismatch between versions but I cannot seem to resolve it

My composer.json:

```
 "name": "laravel/lumen",
    "description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "^7.0",
        "facebook/graph-sdk": "^5.6",
        "laravel/socialite": "^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.5"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message? Packagist does not list any package called `larval/ui`, and even if this should be `laraval/ui`, I don't think installing PHP (which is done when calling `apt-get install php`) will help if Composer is already running

Comment: @NicoHaase the command is composer require laravel/ui "^2.0" -vvv. When I run this, I get the error message Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content. This is the error message I have been receving on every composer command I try.

Comment: Is that the **full** error message? Really nothing else than that?

Comment: @NicoHaase     -
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/inflector[1.4.0, 2.0.3].
  ].
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.

Comment: illuminate/support v5.8.9 requires doctrine/inflector ^1.1 -> satisfiable by doctrine/inflector[1.1.x-dev, 1.2.x-dev, 1.3.1, 1.3.x-dev, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.x-dev, v1.1.0, v1.2.0, v1.3.

Comment: Please add all such information to the question by editing it - don't use the comment section for this

Answer (score 1):

Lumen must be used only to create APIs. You can use an user interface at this. Remember artisan for Lumen is not complete. Some commands isn't allowed. Remember all the interaction in Lumen have be for HTTP protocol.
The Authentication is work a little different in Lumen: https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication

Comment: Please add some further explanation - how does this answer solve the problems on installing something using Composer?

Answer (score 0):

`laravel/socialite` with the given version requirement will install v3.4.0. This is only compatible with Laravel 5.4.

On the other hand, `laravel/lumen-framework` with the given requirement will install any version starting from v7.0.0. This is only compatible with Laravel 7.

You should either downgrade `laravel/lumen-framework` (which I would not recommend, as this only postpones further problems), or upgrade `laravel/socialite` to at least v4.2, which is the first version of this package to be compatible with Laravel 7